# python completion is slow in vim with youcompleteme

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

Every time I import a third-part library, YouCompleteMe cannot work immediately.

e.g. When I input `import numpy as np` and then `np.`, it shows nothing. After a few seconds (maybe 10s or more), when I input `np.`, it can work well and show a list of completion suggestions.

So, how to speed up the procedure? I think that may because YouCompleteMe needs to index the library every time I import?

I use vim 7.4 and the latest version of YouCompleteMe (2016.08.21), on Mac OS 10.11

Thanks!

Comment: Use YCM's mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I found that if you use the tab complete to get the library, then it will instantly find all the members. Otherwise it seems like it will fail. What I mean by this is that if you type numpy. and wait, nothing will happen. But if you type n, then accept numpy with the tab, then type ., it will offer you all the members of numpy.